# In Ember data, what is the best way to form association between two objects?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ember.js, ember-data

Let's say some DS.Model class `Leaf` belongsTo class `Tree`, and one `Tree` hasMany `leaves`, ie:

```
App.Leaf = DS.Model.extend({

    tree:   DS.belongsTo('App.Tree'),

});

App.Tree = DS.Model.extend({

    leaves:   DS.hasMany('App.Leaf'),

})
```

So far I'm manually manipulating `Tree`'s leaves field:

```
tree = App.store.create( App.Tree )
leaf = App.store.create( App.Leaf )
tree.get('leaves').pushObject( leaf )
App.store.commit()
```

Now this appears to work but then things get weird:

when I check leaf's tree field, I see a App.Tree instance is in there and the id matchs that of tree:

```
leaf.get('tree').get('id')  // outputs 1
tree.get('id')             // outputs 1
```

So far ok. Now I check tree's leaves field, which I presume is an Ember mutable-array, and I see this:

```
branch.get('leaves').content  // outputs [ 2 ]
leaf.get('id')                // outputs 1
```

So I presume the leaves mutable-array is storing an array of leaf ids, except its id does not match that of the leaf instance.

Note when the leaf's id is 2, it's stored in the branch.leaves.content field as 4, if leaf id is 3, the stored id is 6, etc.

Comment: your last line makes me think, if the leaf's id is 1, the stored id is 2..?

Comment: Yeah I suppose it wouldn't be a problem except how would I match the stored id to the original object ? Surely I wouldn't just divide by 2, I feel like I'm not understanding something here

Comment: Oh, it was your own conclusion, my bad. M

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this, calling branch.get('leaves').toArray() return an array of materialized records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is working properly in your example, accessing the content variable  `branch.get('leaves')` record array returns an array of the `clientId`'s  of the objects.

However that is the exception as accessing properties any other way will transparently accesses the objects themselves.

In your case if you want ID's use `branch.get('leaves').mapProperty('id')`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So is clientId a different concept than the object's id set at creation? Is there a place I can go to read more about clientId's role in this whole thing?

Comment: A `clientID` is transient and generated when an object is instantiated, the `id` is generally provided by the external data-store. In Ember cliendID's are generally an internal API and you should really not need to interact with them at all